# How to pass value of custom dynamicRows select field in category_form.xml

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, dynamic-rows

I want to save the data in of a custom dynamicrows field. which i added on admin category page. my custom_form.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
            <dynamicRows name="dynamic_rows">
        <settings>
            <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Record</addButtonLabel>
            <additionalClasses>
                <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
            </additionalClasses>
            <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
        </settings>
        <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            
        <field name="selected_product_attributes">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\ProductAttributes</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Attributes</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">selected_product_attributes</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        </container>
    </dynamicRows>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and my Vendor\Module\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\ProductAttributes.php is:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Category\Attribute\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;
class ProductAttributes extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    protected $_productAttributeCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $productAttributeCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_productAttributeCollectionFactory = $productAttributeCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $result = [];
        $attributes = $this->_productAttributeCollectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $result[] = [
                'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                'value' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
            ];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I don't know what should I do next.

Comment: Hey, did you get answer to this?